# How to change wordpress site header dynamically?

Tags: wordpress, header

I want to replace the header of a wordpress site with another in different pages. In other words i want to change wordpress site header dynamically. Kindly help me if there is any solution. The theme of the url is avada. The site url is  https://dev-wishtv.pantheonsite.io/indy-style/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters in get_header() function for using multiple headers for different pages.
for example in about page you can use `get_header('about');`
in blog page you can use `get_header('blog');`

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: But where can i access this get_header() function ? In the header.php page ? I couldn't find it over there.

Comment: You can access get_header() function in different pages. for example in about page you can use get_header('about');

Comment: Thanks a lot. I successfully did that. But i added header background color, main menu, logo as static instead of dynamic as in the first header. How to make these things in the second header too dynamic, at least the main menu?